# PHP - avoid many on-demand imports

Tags: php

I'm trying to create small PHP framework for my own needs (and likes). However there are questions for which I may need advice of more wise and experienced people before things became too complicated - so I moved it to github from private repo.

Currently I'm curious about organizing imports of modules better. I use the special object, "context" - to hold links to all necessary modules - data access objects, utils etc. I use lazy initialization here, so that when field of this object is required, it is provided by the getter of the same name.

It looks like:

```
class ProtoContext {

    function __get($name) {
        $methodName = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
        if (!method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
            throw new Exception("No property '$name' in Context!");
        }
        $res = $this->$methodName();
        if (is_object($res)) {
            $res->ctx = $this;
        }
        $this->$name = $res;
        return $res;
    }

    protected function getElems() {
        return Elems::$elems;
    }

    protected function getUtil() {
        module('sys/Util');
        return new Util();
    }

}
```

main [Context](https://github.com/RodionGork/PhpLayout/blob/master/module/Context.php) class is inherited from this [ProtoContext](https://github.com/RodionGork/PhpLayout/blob/master/module/sys/ProtoContext.php), though it is not significant now. With the grow of application context may look like this:

```
module('sys/ProtoContext');

class Context extends ProtoContext {

    protected function getAuth() {
        module('MyAuth');
        return new MyAuth();
    }

    protected function getUsersDao() {
        module('dao/MysqlDao');
        return new MysqlDao('users');
    }

    protected function getRolesDao() {
        module('dao/MysqlDao');
        return new MysqlDao('roles');
    }

    /*
     * 5-10 more similar methods 'getSomethingDao'    
     * each including MysqlDao via method 'module'
     */

    protected function getLinksCViewDao() {
        module('dao/MysqlDao');
        return new MysqlDao('linksc_view');
    }

}
```

There is no problem that `module` method may be called several times, include is performed once only. However it looks annoying that inclusion of MysqlDao is mentioned so many times. On the other hand if I pull it above the class (like import of ProtoContext) it will be imported even if I need it not. For example when addressing $ctx->auth field (which will call getAuth method).

I wonder, whether here is comfortable workaround which will preserve lazy load and lazy initialization - and at the same time will allow to get rid of extra imports?

Comment: Why would you implement `module` method if we already have lazy loading trough autoloading? It looks to me you're doing something that's been done before (and much better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As N.B. mentioned in their comment - why are you implementing a `module` method if we already have lazy loading via autoloading? I've even [written a class](https://github.com/jsanc623/LazyLoader) that you can simply attach and not have to worry about loading your classes. Now, there are better autoloaders out there - like [Symphony's ClassLoader/autoload.php](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html). Anyways, here's your code, with my LazyLoader class handling the loading of methods (untested code).

**/LazyLoader.php**

```
/**
 * LazyLoader
 * A fast, strict lazy loader (time ~ 0.0001)
 * 
 * Class name must match File name.
 * If class has namespace, must be called via namespace.
 *
 * @author Juan L. Sanchez <juanleonardosanchez.com>
 * @license MIT
 * @version 1.2.0
 * @internal 06.26.2013
 */

Namespace LazyLoader;

class LazyLoader{
    public static $dirRoot;

    public static function autoload($class_name){
        $file = dirname(__FILE__) . 
                (strlen(self::$dirRoot) > 0 ? self::$dirRoot : "") . 
                '/' . array_pop(explode("\\", $class_name)) . '.php';

        file_exists($file) ? require_once($file) : "";
    }

    public static function SetBaseDirectory($directory_root){
        self::$dirRoot = substr($directory_root, -1) == "\\" ? 
                         substr($directory_root, 0, -1) : "";
    }

    public static function Register(){
        return spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ .'\LazyLoader::autoload');
    }
}

$LazyLoader = new LazyLoader;
$LazyLoader->SetBaseDirectory("Classes"); # Optional
$LazyLoader->Register();
```

**/Context.php**

```
<?php
module('sys/ProtoContext');

class Context extends ProtoContext {

    protected function getAuth() {
        return new MyAuth();
    }

    protected function getUsersDao() {
        return new MysqlDao('users');
    }

    protected function getRolesDao() {
        return new MysqlDao('roles');
    }

    /*
     * 5-10 more similar methods 'getSomethingDao'    
     * each including MysqlDao via method 'module'
     */

    protected function getLinksCViewDao() {
        return new MysqlDao('linksc_view');
    }

}
```

The directory structure of the above code would look something like:

```
/LazyLoader.php
/Context.php
/Classes/MyAuth.php
/Classes/ProtoContext.php
/Classes/MysqlDao.php
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. `is_readable` might be an improvement over `file_exists`.

Comment: `is_readable` tests whether a file exists and is readable, whereas `file_exists` tests whether a file, well, exists - but doesn't check readability. If the file is not readable, it should fail loudly in the require_once, rather than failing quietly when using `is_readable` and/or `include`. That was my line of thinking. Is there a performance difference between `is_readable` and `file_exists`? That would be surely negated by my use of `require_once` I'd imagine?